# In my application I need to record every incoming and outgoing call

Tags: java, android

**Below is the code of receiver class**

```
package com.example.crecording;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.IInterface;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class callReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          phoneListener phonestateListener = new phoneListener(context);
          TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          telephony.listen(phonestateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }

    class phoneListener extends PhoneStateListener{
        private Context context;
        phoneListener(Context c){
            super();
            context=c;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
             SharedPreferences preferences =     context.getSharedPreferences("CallReceiver", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE :
                Toast.makeText(context, state+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                     String phone_number = preferences.getString("phone_number",null);
                     Intent serv = new Intent(context,
                     cRecordingservice.class);
                     serv.putExtra("number", phone_number);
                     context.startService(serv);

                     Toast.makeText(context, state+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                     break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING :
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                   editor.putString("phone_number", incomingNumber);
                   editor.commit();
                   Toast.makeText(context, state+""+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Below is the code for Call recording service**

```
    package com.example.crecording;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class cRecordingservice extends Service  {
    MediaRecorder callrecorder;
    Boolean recording;
    MainActivity main=new MainActivity();
    BroadcastReceiver myreceiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        myphonestatelistener mpl=new myphonestatelistener(context);
        TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(mpl,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        }

        class myphonestatelistener extends PhoneStateListener{
            private Context context;

            myphonestatelistener(Context c){
                context=c;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if(recording){
                        stopRecording();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    if(!recording){
                    startRecording();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                    break;


                }
            }



        }
            };



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         IntentFilter RecFilter = new IntentFilter();
         RecFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
         RecFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
         registerReceiver(myreceiver, RecFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myreceiver);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      startRecording();
        return  START_STICKY;


    }



    void startRecording(){
        String root="/sdcard/";
        String fname="rec"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".amr";
        File file=new File(root,fname);
        callrecorder=new MediaRecorder();
        callrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        callrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        callrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        callrecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath()
                );
        try {
            callrecorder.prepare();

            callrecorder.start();
            recording=true;
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.printStackTrace(),3000 ).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


void stopRecording(){

        callrecorder.stop();
//      callrecorder.release();
        callrecorder.reset();
        recording=false;

    }





}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Intent intent2;
    static MediaRecorder callrecorder;
    static Boolean recording=false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Service", 10000).show();
                intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cRecordingservice.class);
//                getApplicationContext().startService(intent2);    

            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop Service", 10000).show();
                intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cRecordingservice.class);
                getApplicationContext().stopService(intent2);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Below is the manifest code**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crecording.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.crecording.callReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.example.crecording.cRecordingservice" ></service>
</application>
```

**After changes app is able to record one call but after that it makes file of unrecognised format & append file to the current file.I dont know why this happens**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. In particular, please explain what "not being done by this" means.

Comment: call is not being recorded,as u can see i have added code of startrecording in call_state_offhook.But this code is not even called.Could not get it,why this code is not being called  on call state changed..

Comment: Above is code of receiver & service class,I want it to record every call.But i am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Above is code of receiver & service class,I want it to record every call.But i am not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you start your recording service when the phone state changes (for example, from "idle" to "offhook"). But then in that service you don't register your broadcast receiver to listen for phone state changes and you also don't ever start recording, so nothing ever happens.

You should pass data to the service to tell it the phone state change when it starts, then make sure you register your broadcast receiver when it starts. You will also need to handle the fact that you now have two broadcast receivers listening for phone state changes and possibly starting and stopping your recording.

Comment: Can u plz tell me if two receivers Disturb each other ? And can u plz Explain more.

Comment: The two receivers can be OK. But if one has your service change recording state and then the other does the same, then it will toggle on/off. Or if your recording object gets messed up by calling "start" twice in a row because the service "onstart" method starts recording and so does the service's broadcast receiver after it's registered, you will have problems. The problem now is that you need to call registerReceiver(myreceiver, filters) in your service's onStart method and also check to see if it should start recording at the time it starts, and do so if necessary.

Comment: I have done what u said.But it records only one call...after that it gives error n crashes

Comment: You have an NPE at line 44. Looks like you make static calls to MainActivity methods elsewhere, but then try to instantiate it when the service is constructed, then reference it on that line. You didn't post code for "MainActivity" ...

Comment: i have removed the npe by some changes,but now the app records only one call.on second call it generate a file  unrecognised by player.Mainly it just record one call.What is the problem with code.

Comment: read up on MediaRecorder - you're calling "reset" ; you probably want to release()... you're also not setting your "recording" flag properly. This is really just debugging - helping you understand how a service and broadcast receiver work together is one thing, but you should be able to solve this at this point.

Comment: Thanx for ur valueable comments.I want to be able to do all these things but m new to android thats why these mistakes happens.

Comment: Let us know if you get it done. And please check this as the correct answer if it got you there. thx